# Applications in the Windows Registry

Tags: windows-registry

Where is Applications/program_name.exe in the Windows Registry? I've got a problem with InDesign.exe not being accepted as the default application for its .indd file extension. I've altered every registry entry I can find, but can't locate where the registry stores the list of programs that comes up when a user wants to associate a program with an extension. For some reason InDesign can't be selected as a default program. It used to default to Acrobat until I changed the entry to remove that option.

Comment: Which program opens when you now double-click a .indd file? Which version of indesign are you using? Also did you have an older version of indesign on this computer?

Answer (score 2):

I also had the problem with InDesign.exe not being accepted as the default application for its .indd file extension. I experienced also simmilar symptoms.

The cause: I had two versions of InDesign installed, uninstalled the earlier version and then the file association link broke and I could not fix it.

The cure: After searching for help at http://forums.adobe.com/message/1976149 the forum entry 35 from user bkepl was the right suggestion (for me, at least):

Quoting adobe forum "CS4 .indd file association problem" entry 35. of bkepl from May 2012:

> Open the registry editor [...] and browse to: Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\InDesign.exe\shell\open\command
>
> [check the ...]
> full path to your installation of InDesign. In my case: "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe InDesign CS5.5\InDesign.exe" "%1"